# Quite large (400k) mysql database design for multiple users

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm seeking advice of experienced admins.

I'm working on a website, where you solve word anagrams. If it solved it should never be displayed again.

Wordbase contains ~400k entries. What would be the most effective solution to storing such data?

One way could be:

```
+---------+------------------------+
| word_id | user1 | user2 | user...|
+---------+------------------------+
|  1      | null  |  null |  1     |
|  2      | 1     |  null |  null  |
|  ...    |       |       |        |
|  400000 | null  |  1    |  null  |
+---------+------------------------+
```

Where let's say 1 = solved.

But wouldn't it become a monster quite quickly?
(+even a simple query of extending it by a new user takes forever)

Other solution is to store every solved word_id for all users, but then, it can be 6-digits for every entry and growing massively and rapidly aswell.

Also which engine would be more effective in this example? MyISAM or    InnoDB?

Comment: Not really adding much to this, but a comment nonetheless. 400k records is not even close to being remotely quite large

Comment: @ChrisBint Mysql newbie's vocabulary, sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not put the users as columns.  If I understand the question, you would have a table, called something like `WordUsers` with one row per "word" and one per "user":

```
create table WordUsers (
    WordUserId int not null primary key auto_increment,
    WordId int not null,
    UserId int not null,
    . . .
    constraint fk_WordId foreign key (WordId) references Words(WordId),
    constraint fk_UserId foreign key (UserId) references Users(UserId)
);
```

When a word is shown to a user, then you add a row to this table.  The `. . .` can include other information, such as the date/time of the interaction.

Comment: yep, I thought putting users as columns was a big no-no, so thank you for clarifying

Comment: `WordUserId int not null primary key auto_increment` is a waste; simply have `PRIMARY KEY(WordId, UserId)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your database supports it (and I think all of them do now) - why not just put either a text field on the user's table, fill it with a string of "N"s for "No - they haven't seen this word yet" and when they are given a word just change the "N" to "Y" for that record/word and re-save the new string?  A TEXT string can be up to 65,536 characters long.  So you make your string something like 5,000 "N"s.

Or if you want to beat yourself up a bit - use the BIT field and make it something like 5000 flags.  Same concept but harder to use.

BTW: On the string of "N"s and "Y"s you should be able to make an SQL query which has something like "WHERE SUBSTR(SEEN_IT,WORD_ID,1)='N'" kind of test.

Comment: `TINYTEXT` is limited to 256 _bytes_.

Comment: @RickJames : You are right!  I should have said to use TEXT and not TINYTEXT. Modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Still not quite correct -- _bytes_, not _characters_.  For utf8, that can be a factor of 3 in difference.

Comment: @RickJames : Yes.  But you could also set it to one of the 16 or 32 UTF character types also which would really muck it up.  I think I'll leave it as characters because I consider the term "characters" to be whatever type of characters the person is using.  ASCII, UTF-8,16, or 32. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You should use a relational database, like it should be, relational:

```
CREATE TABLE user( user_id int autoincrement, user CHAR(16));
CREATE TABLE word( word_id int autoincrement, word CHAR(16));
CREATE TABLE solved( word_id, user_id);
```

Comment: Can you provide some reasoning with more substance than "well it ain't called a *relational* database for nothing"